# High-power capacitor charger

Tags: charging, supercapacitor

I am trying to put together a circuit that can charge a 3000 F Maxwell supercapacitor in about 10 mins.

I am looking to use a 150 W laptop adapter and a buck converter. Here are the problems that I am encountering:

1. No high-power buck converters with 2-3 V output to charge the supercapacitor safely.
2. I do not have enough knowledge on the concept of having several buck converters in parallel to increase power output.
3. Cost.

Comment: What  power dissipation do you expect thru the Cap ESR?

Comment: What budget limit do you have? and other realistic physical constraints considering 100A charge rates.

Comment: Look at multiple phase or synchornizable buck converters - they are typically used in PCs to power the CPU or GPU - those 150W get stepped down from 12V to around 1V.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a power calculation first: The charge \$Q\$ on a capacitor with capacity \$C\$ under voltage \$U\$ is:

$$
\begin{align}
Q&= CU\\
 &= 3000\,F \cdot 3\,V\\
 &= 3000\,\frac{As}{V} \cdot 3\,V\\
 &= 9000\,As\,\text.
\end{align}
$$

That's quite a handful of Energy:

$$
\begin{align}
E&= QU\\
 &= 9000\,As \cdot 3\,V\\
 &= 27\, kVAs\\
 &= 27\, kWs\\
 &= 27\, kJ\,\text.
\end{align}
$$

27 kJ is not a fun thing. If you wanted to charge that within 10 min = 600s, your **average** current and power would have to be

$$
\begin{align}
I_{avg} &= \frac{9000\,As}{600\,s}\\
&= \frac{90}6\,A \\
&= 15\,A\,\text{,}\\
P_{avg} &= \frac{27\,kJ}{600\,s}\\
&= 45\,W
\end{align}
$$

so, assuming a typical 20V for your laptop supply, and following your claim it delivers up to 150W, it's instantaneous maximum output current is 7.5A, less than 15A – in other words, you'll really need that step-down converter if you want to do this in 10 Minutes.

Sadly, capacitors don't charge continuously – they have exponentially decreasing voltage gap == current, so at the beginning, you'd have an immense charge current.

So, you *could* certainly design a very beefy step-down (buck) converter that is able to source 100s of ampere for a short time, but you could also just design something that avoids the whole inductivity thing – after all, you don't care about the voltage at all, until it reaches your desired final value; that will take longer, will burn a lot of energy, but it's also much easier to implement:

Basically:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkD5rf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another, better, since less inefficient, method would be using an Opamp over a smaller shunt resistance instead of R1 to sink a constant current (==max current of your supply) into the capacitor, and use the comparator/reference voltage only to turn that off.

But: you could also take this comparator-only circuit and omit R1, probably. Why? Because consumer electronic, sufficiently cooled, will probably just shut off in an overload situation, and switch back on as soon as things have cooled down. That way, you can use the step-down power supply that your laptop supply essentially is ... I wouldn't call this a good solution, but it's definitely the easiest one, and worst case, it costs you a laptop supply.

Comment: Don't laugh but one winter when I was poor, married  2 kids in -30'C deg weather with a dead battery ( around 10k Farads) I charged it up in about 30 minutes with a 25A power diode bridge mounted in a cup of snow ice water steaming away and 120Vac Line thru toaster in series to Vbat+ with car frame at Neutral voltage. It worked and I got to work.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 not surprised; I charged my Punto's car battery in my student dorm with a grid-to-20V printer transformator, and a sturdy bridge rectifier, mounted with a screw to a hole in an aluminium window frame that miraculously always had been there. The bridge rectifier did get hot, but was OK, and so did the transformer; I got a peak charge current of ~8A out of that poor 2A-rated thing by wrapping it in a plastic bag and keeping it in my filled sink, with cold water continously dripping in

Comment: why not modify your linear regulator with a high current choke and ground side current shunt to make a hysteretic buck converter to regulate current

Comment: because I'd have to admit I'd be scared by the side effects of designing my own stepdown converter – from EMI to heating problems.

Comment: try the Falstad simulator and add ESR to each part with high current, it will compute and scope power dissipation, <select part> > add to scope. It uses a mix of limited parts and ideal parts but many circuits

Comment: I must admit that if I was actually tasked with creating a >>10W step down, I'd probably get some literature, a simulator, app notes from a couple of SMPS controller silicon manufacturers... for answering OP's question, that sounds like a bit more than my spare time allows :)

Comment: also, thinking about this, my guess would be that Linear tech has controller ICs that can deal with such situation, given beefy enough coils and MOSFETs

Comment: e.g. the [LTC3866](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3866); a bit of circuitry involved, but I generally like Linear's datasheets and app notes and there's probably a suitable eval circuit around

Comment: note that this is nothing OP is likely to use in the end – the "easiest" package is TSSOP24...

Comment: Minor comment - your calculation of energy and power is out by a factor of 2.  The energy is 0.5*CV^2.  13500J or 22.5W for a ten minute charge.

Comment: Although D.S. Last seen Dec 1 '16 at 11:08, @ Community bumped it up now. @MarcusMüller , I agree with 60W based on 15A and 0.26mΩ.  >> Kevin this means charging requires much higher V+ to charge at 15A, so the loss is not the same as the reactive energy!. .Dielectrics are thermal insulators  could heat up this cap too much for comfort.  This question is no different than the capacitance of a LiPo cell with 5mΩ ESR  trying to quick charge it in 10 minutes with disastrous results . I just checked and this Cap has a 11,000 A Is.c. rating, with an initial ESR of 0.27 mΩ so \$I^2ESR=15^2*0.27m=60W

Answer (score 0):

You need a good current limited power module that can take a short on the output.  The 3000F cap will look like a short until its charged.  Ordinary modules that just output voltage will not work.

Synqor makes some modules but they are expensive.
http://www.synqor.com/

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off application where you don't care how large or clunky the power supply is, look at using an old PC motherboard.

Most modern CPU chips run somewhere between 1.5 Vdc through 3.3 Vdc. Older CPU chips generally run higher voltage.

There is often a 5-bit digital word that sets the exact output voltage of the CPU power supply.

This should get you started towards a very inexpensive solution.

Comment: "There is often a 5-bit digital word that sets the exact output voltage of the CPU power supply. " - yeah but you don't have a way to set that without extensive knowledge of the internals of the particular motherboard.

Comment: Go into the BIOS and set the voltage as displayed.  Assuming the mobo still works and that it has integrated video, that is.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOcCcm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Something like this might work. The input is a 120V RMS source, and the capacitor charges to about 300 mV in 100 seconds, at about 50 amps peak. The actual power used depends on ESR of components. Of course a true buck converter with inductor would be better, and this idea may be impractical, and would take about 1000 seconds to reach the 3V or so required.

[image: Capacitor charge voltage after 100 seconds]
[image: Input and capacitor currents]
[image: Details of charging current]
[image: 3000F current 600s]
[image: 3000F capacitor voltage 600s]